# Creating cell references in a Call to another macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I'm trying to copy a variable number of rows of data (values and formats) from one worksheet to another. To do this I found and successfully some VBA code on the web that will copy a single cell at a time `Copy_ValueFormat(cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range)`

But the Call crashes when I call that code from within nested For Loops.  I'm clearly not formatting the cell references in the Call correctly as I am getting the following error: [Run-time error '9':  Subscript out of Range]

Can anyone out there tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
'THIS IS THE VBA I GOT OFF THE
'Copy Value and formats from one cell to another
Sub Copy_ValueFormat(cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range)
Dim sel As Range
Set sel = Selection

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

cell1.Copy
cell2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

cell1.Copy
cell2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

sel.Activate
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub



'THIS IS SOME TEST CODE THAT SUCCESSFULLY CALLS   "Copy_ValueFormat(...)"
Sub TestCopy()
Call Copy_ValueFormat(Range("ONGOING!B2"), Range("BF2"))
End Sub



'THIS IS MY CODE THA CRASHES WHEN I MAKE THE CALL TO "Copy_ValueFormat(...)"
Sub TestForNext()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Sheets("JUNK").Select
Cells.ClearContents

For i = 1 To 10   'Row Counter
    For j = 1 To 20   'Column Counter
    Call Copy_ValueFormat(Sheets("ONGOING!").Cells(i, j), Sheets("JUNK").Cells(i, j))
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Why aren't you doing this in a single copy & paste values/formats? e.g. `ONGOING!A1:T20 ~> JUNK!A1:T20`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to select something to work on it and the idea of collecting the current selection in order to return to it is unnecessary. The `Application.ScreenUpdating` calls only serve to blink the screen.

Using `Call` to run a sub procedure has been grandfathered out of use. Note that without it, the passed parameters are not bracketed.

The original copy source is still there after xlPasteFormats; you don't need to copy it again.

```
Sub Copy_ValueFormat(cell1 As Range, cell2 As Range)

    cell1.Copy
    cell2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    cell2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub

Sub TestForNext()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    'if you want to halt screen updating, this is where it should be
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Worksheets("JUNK")

        .Cells.Clear    '<~~ clear values and formats

        For i = 1 To 10   'Row Counter
            For j = 1 To 20   'Column Counter
                Copy_ValueFormat Worksheets("ONGOING!").Cells(i, j), .Cells(i, j)
            Next j
        Next i

    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanx Jeeped,  I ran your code as sent and I got a "Subscript out of Range" error again. I'm beginning thing there is another issue.

Comment: Does your `ONGOING!` really end in an exclamation mark or did you accidentally copy the `!` along with the rest from a cell reference in a formula?